# How to filter a set of chars from a string in Elixir 1.3.2

Tags: string, filter, char, elixir

I have a MAC address stored as "ac:cf:5c:e1:b5:e0" for example.

I'd like to capitalise all chars in the string and drop ":" from the string.

Is this the best way?

```
mu_mac="ac:cf:5c:e1:b5:e0"
String.upcase(mu_mac) |> String.to_charlist |> Enum.filter(&(&1 != 58))
```

Comment: In future if you've got a potential solution in your mind, you should include that information in the question.

Answer (score 6):

I would go with:

```
mu_mac="ac:cf:5c:e1:b5:e0"
mu_mac |> String.upcase |> String.replace(":", "")
```

or:

```
mu_mac |> String.upcase |> String.split(":") |> Enum.join
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do so (for me):

```
a = "ac:cf:5c:e1:b5:e0"
a |> String.replace(":", "") |> String.upcase
```

Comment: Maybe the first one wasn't posted when this answer was started. It's easy to miss. Be kind.

Comment: It's a good answer and, as Martin points out, it's entirely possible they were posted semi-simultaneously.